# Blocking Alts From Joining

Tags: javascript, discord.js

So i'm trying to implement a protection inside my private bot and so far i've been struggling to make it work, the only thing i got to work was if a bot join it will get banned.

`bot.on('guildMemberAdd', (member) => { if(member.user.bot) member.ban().catch(e=>console.log(e))})`

But what i really want is to ban any alt that was recently created and not 30 days old. if anyone could help that would be much appreciated and thank you

Answer (score 1):

You're going to need to get the [`GuildMember`'s](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember) [`User`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User) and then get either the [`createdAt`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User?scrollTo=createdAt) or the [`createdTimestamp`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User?scrollTo=createdTimestamp) property which you will then use to compare to the current time to know how old the account is and then using that to do an if statement that bans the `GuildMember` using the [`.ban()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=ban) method.

Inside your `guildMemberAdd` event, type the following:

```js
const accAge = Math.abs(Date.now() - member.user.createdAt);
const accDays = Math.ceil(accAge / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
if (accDays <= 30) member.ban();
```